# Symfony2 multiple applications and api centric application

Tags: api, rest, web-applications, architecture, symfony

I'm trying to do a Symfony2 centric application and re-use all the Bundles for the web front app. The application will be divided in three API, FrontEnd, BackEnd, so that we can code the API like a Service Bundle and use it across the hole application and also will provide an API for our application. The FrontEnd will use the API as a Service and it will have all the front for user use. And the BackEnd will also use the API but providing a different url to admin the app.

This is the structure I'm using:

```
/app_api  
/app_frontend  
/app_backend  
/bin  
/src  
/vendor  
/web_api  
/web_frontend  
/web_backend
```

This will be traduced to:

```
api.domain.com (app_api, web_api)  
www.domain.com (app_frontend, web_frontend)  
backend.domain.com (app_backend, web_backend)
```

What do you think?
Is this posible?
What about performance, even if we are using APC?

If you have another solution let me know.

Thanks & Regards to everyone

Comment: I do almost the same thing except I have apps/api,apps/frontend,apps/backend.  And individual directories under web as well.  Seems to work fine.

Comment: Thanks for you reply!, I guess that structure is also very good and maybe better

Comment: How do you configure the app to update vendors on all apps? Regards