# Multiple applications in the same Symfony2 application

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

This is quite a long question, but there's quite a lot to it.
It feels like it should be a reasonably common use case, so I'm hoping the Stack Overflow community can provide me with a 'best practice in Symfony2' answer.

The solution I describe below works, but there are several consequences I'd like to avoid:

1. In my local dev environment, if I have used the wrong db connection the test will work in dev but fail on production
2. The routes of the ADMIN API are accessible on the PUBLIC API url, just denied.
3. If I have a mirror of live in my dev environment (3 separate checkouts with the corresponding parameters.yml file) then the feature tests for the other bundles fail

**Is there a 'best practice in Symfony2' way to set up my project?**

We're running a LAMP stack. We use git/(Atlassian) stash for version control.
We're using doctrine for the ORM and FOS-REST with OAuth plus symfony firewalls to authenticate and authorise the users.
We're committed to use Symfony2, so I am trying to find a 'best practice' solution:

I have a project with 3 applications:

1. A public-facing API (which gives read-only access to the data)
2. A protected API (which provides admin functionality)
3. A set of batch processes (to e.g. import data and monitor data quality)

Each application uses a set of shared models.

I have created 4 bundles, one each for the application and a 4th for the shared models.

Each application must use a different database user to access the database.
There's only one database.
There's several tables, one is called 'prices'

The admin API only must be accessible from one hostname (e.g. admin-api.server1) 
The public API only must be accessible from a different hostname (e.g. public-api.server2) 
Each application is hosted on a different server

In parameters.yml in my dev environment I have this
    // parameters.yml
    api_public_db_user: user1
    api_public_db_pass: pass1

```
api_admin_db_user: user2
api_admin_db_pass: pass2

batch_db_user: user3
batch_db_pass: pass3
```

In config.yml I have this:

```
// config.yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            api_public:
                user:     "%api_public_db_user%"
                password: "%api_public_db_pass%"
            api_admin:
                user:     "%api_admin_db_user%"
                password: "%api_admin_db_pass%"
            batch:
                user:     "%batch_db_user%"
                password: "%batch_db_pass%"
```

In my code I can do this (I believe this can be done from the service container too, but I haven't got that far yet)

```
$entityManager = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager('api_public');
$entityRepository = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getRepository('CommonBundle:Price', api_admin');
```

When I deploy my code to each of the live servers, I put junk values in the parameters.yml for the other applications

```
// parameters.yml on the public api server
api_public_db_user: user1
api_public_db_pass: pass1

api_admin_db_user: **JUNK**
api_admin_db_pass: **JUNK**

batch_db_user: **JUNK**
batch_db_pass: **JUNK**
```

1. I have locked down my application so that the database isn't accessible (and thus the other API features don't work)
2. I have also set up Symfony firewall security so that the different routes require different permissions
3. There's also security in the apache vhost to deny access to say the admin api path from the public api directory.

So, I have secured my application and met the requirement of the security audit, but the dev process isn't ideal and something feels wrong.

As background:

- We have previously looked at splitting it up into different applications within the same project (like this [Symfony2 multiple applications and api centric application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523908/symfony2-multiple-applications-and-api-centric-application). Actually followed this method http://jolicode.com/blog/multiple-applications-with-symfony2) , but ran into difficulties, and in any case, Fabien says not to (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony-devs/yneojUuFiqw). That this existed in Symfony1 and was removed in Symfony2 is enough of an argument for me.
- We have previously gone down the route of splitting up each bundle and importing it using composer, but this caused too many development overheads (for example, having to modify many repositories to implement a feature; it not being possible to see all of the changes for a feature in a single pull request).
- We are receiving an ever growing number of requests to create APIs, and we're similarly worried about putting each application in its own repository.
  So, putting each of the three applications in a separate Symfony project / git repository is something we want to avoid too.

Comment: Tricky topic.  I haven't had much success when using the same entities across multiple entity managers in a single application to separate out the database user that connects, say to have a different user connecting to admin vs. the main application.  That Fabien post is from 4 years ago, and sure it may still apply, but for your case it may be better to just have 3 individual applications and then a single bundle containing all of your common code/entities/repository calls/etc.